# Haskell: type inference and function composition

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, function-composition

This question was inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334488/how-do-i-remove-every-occurance-of-a-value-from-a-list-in-haskell-using-prelude/1335530#1335530) to another question, indicating that you can remove every occurrence of an element from a list using a function defined as:

```
removeall = filter . (/=)
```

Working it out with pencil and paper from the types of `filter`, `(/=)` and `(.)`, the function has a type of

```
removeall :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

which is exactly what you'd expect based on its contract. However, with GHCi 6.6, I get

```
gchi> :t removeall
removeall :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

unless I specify the type explicitly (in which case it works fine). Why is Haskell inferring such a specific type for the function?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Why is Haskell inferring such a specific type for the function?

GHCi is using [type defaulting](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules), to infer a more specific type from a set of possibles. You can avoid this easily by disabling [the monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/monomorphism.html),

```
Prelude> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
Prelude> let removeall = filter . (/=)
Prelude> :t removeall 
removeall :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Answer (score 17):

It is also worth noting that if you don't assign a name to the expression, typechecker seems to avoid type defaulting:

```
Prelude> :t filter . (/=)
filter . (/=) :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
```